# Dupla consulta em 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tenho 2 tabelas uma de usuarios e outra de inscritos, tenho um insert que envia para a tabela de inscritos o email do usuario que cadastrou e o nome do canal

1ª usuarios

```
id | usuario  | meucanal 
1  | a@a.com  | portados fundos 
2  | b@b.com  | parafernalha
3  | c@c.com  | Ei nerd
4  | d@d.com  | Canal Nostalgia
```

2ª inscricoes

```
id | usuario | se_inscreveu_no_canal
1  | a@a.com   | Ei nerd
2  | a@a.com   | parafernalha
```

Resumindo o que preciso é fazer um SELECT liste somente os canais que o usuario ainda nao se inscreveu no caso do exemplo o a@a.com precisa ser exibido somente o Canal Nostalgia

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE canal NOT EXIST IN(SELECT * FROM inscricoes WHERE o_usuario NOT IN se_inscreveu_no_canal) ORDER BY RAND();
```

Não sou profissional da area, apenas programo como hobby porem coisas mais simplre esse tipo de consulta é mais avançada se puderem me auxiliar em um caminho pra solução desde ja agradeço.

Segue um pouco da estrutura para melhor entendimento(bem resumida)

cadastro.php

insira seu email e o nome do seu canal

INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, canal) VALUES ('$_POST[email]',$_POST[canal]')";
**CADASTRO PRONTO**

listarcanais.php ( o usuario nesta parte ja estara logado $user=session[email])
SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY canal LIMIT 1";
echo " CLIQUE AQUI PARA SE ISNCREVER ";

inscrever.php ( o usuario nesta parte ja estara logado $user=session[email])
$canal= $GET[canal];
INSERT INTO inscricoes (usuario, canal) VALUES ('$user,$canal')";
//redirect to listarcanais.php
**PRONTO JA CONSTA NO BD QUE O USUARIO JA INSCREVEU NAQUELE CANAL**

listarcanais.php <<< como na minha cabeça acha que o sistema deveria ler

SELECIONE canal FROM (tabela usuarios) ONDE  o (usuario=$user) NÂO se inscreveu ( na tabela inscricoes)

no grosso modo: 1° um select que pega o (email/$user) e compara as tabelas USUARIOS e INSCRICOES afim de eliminar os outros email que nao é o do $user

feito isso 2° um select que lista todos os canais da tabela USUARIOS e compara com todos os canais da tabela INSCRICOES . Os que não forem iguais serão listado

Comment: A estrutura do seu banco pode (acredito que deve) ser melhorada, sugiro uma tabela usuario e outra canal, numa relação N:N em que a terceira tabela gerada contenha o id do usuario e o id dos canais que ele está inscrito

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    distinct(canal)
FROM
    usuarios
WHERE
    email <> '$email'
    AND
    canal NOT IN (
        SELECT canal FROM inscricoes WHERE email = '$email'

   )
```

Answer (score -2):

Só existe apenas essas duas tabelas, não existe uma tabela de canal? Como é registrado todos os canais existentes?

Havendo três tabelas: `Usuarios`, `Canais` e `Inscricoes`, onde `Inscricoes` é relacionamento de muitos-para-muitos entre `Usuarios` e `Canais`, então assim basta trazer os `Canais` que não existem em `Inscricoes` por `Usuarios`.

```
select u.nome as usuario, c.nome as canal
from usuarios u, canais c
where not exists (select 1 from inscricoes i where i.cod_canal =c.cod_canal and i.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario);
```

Comment: entao todos os canais registrados estao na tabela usuario cada usuario so pode ter 1 canal, na hora que o usuario vai cadastrar no sistema ele ja informa o nome do canal basicamente so pego o email e o nome do canal

Comment: Sugiro que faça como foi sugerido pelo Guilherme, faça uma relação de muitos para muitos, assim vai ficar normalizado, mais simples para a manutenção e realização de consultas